# How do I create a new page for each user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create a new page for each user on signup so when you go to the site's explore page and  click  on someone's name or picture, it will take you to their specific page and display their data. (database is firebase firestore and firebase storage, saved link to each person's doc)
This is one of the issues I've been trying to fix for about a month(just fixed the explore page issue and got everyone profile pic to display with that individual user's name right below). I have tried making a new html page with someone's php and js script (didn't work, not familiar with php) and url rewriting.
I haven't been able to find anything else concrete or at least something else to point me in the right direction. Any pointers or tips?
(Vanilla/node.js)

Comment: You do not make a new page for each user but output the data from firebase relevant to the logged in user. With PHP you can create a session for logged in user and then, retrieve all info where username and password correlates with a user in the database. Without seeing a sample code there isn't much help to be rendered.

Comment: I don't think I phrased it correctly. I set up the settings page so people can view and update their own info but I'm trying to let people see other people's data. For example if it was on instagram and I was on Sanchovies' page, the link would be https://www.instagram.com/sanchovie/ but if I was on ricegum's page, it'd be https://www.instagram.com/rice/

Comment: Then if you use PHP, on clicking a persons username you can add the username as a parameter to the url e.g (yoursite.com?user=personsusername) then use GET method to retrieve the username and output data relating to that username from the database

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Thanks! I'd upvote/like your comment but idk how.

Comment: added it as an answer, so you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP, on clicking a persons username you can add the username as a parameter to the url e.g `yoursite.com?user=personsusername` then use GET method to retrieve the username and output data relating to that username from the database